# font size problem, normal method doesn't work

Tags: fonts

My ubuntu font size is too small, although the menu and title size is normal. The font of file name and desktop is very small, as the following picture shows. I tried many ways, it just doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? If yes, are you using Unity on other desktop environment or original one?

Comment: Are you using 4k displays ?

Comment: Yes. I am using ubuntu, and I use the original desktop environment. I am not using 4k plays. It used to be normal, but It just became so small. Once I can fix this problem by updating the system software, but now this method doesn't work anymore.